# How to display first name and last name in drop down list in yii2

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I have Employee model, controller and view. Employee table contains FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, etc.

Now I wanted to display Employee FirstName and LastName together in yii2 dropdown list. How to do that?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown list expects items as an array. Just concat first, middle and last name, add it to the array and pass it into the dropdown method.

```
$names = [trim($employee->firstName .  ' ' . $employee->middleName .  ' ' .        $employee->lastName)];
echo dropDownList('full-name', null, $names);
```

Or you can define a fullName method for Employee and use that.

Inside Employee class

```
public function getFullName() {
    return trim($this->firstName . ' ' . $this->middleName . ' ' . $this->lastName);
}
```

Usage

```
$names = [$employee->fullName];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayHelper` . First Import `ArrayHelper` class as below.

`use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;`

Assuming your variable name as `$model`. Map `id` with `first_name` and `last_name` as below.

`$data=ArrayHelper::map($model,'id',function($model){ return $model->first_name.' '.$model->last_name;});`

Code for dropdown

`<?php echo $form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList($data); ?>`